# When splitting traffic to different versions of your app, which version is the default version

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

This question is related to an issue when running a Python 2 and Python 3 version of an application with split traffic that uses the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue).

Looking at the [`taskqueue.py`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/main/src/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py) module, I've gathered that the target for the `Task` is set to the `DEFAULT_APP_VERSION`, however I do not know how this is determined when two versions of the app are considered the *default* version.

Comment: I read the documentation on Task Queue and it is only applicable for Python 2. As of the moment, Python 2 is no longer supported on GCP and it is recommended to [migrate to Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3).  Are you using both Python versions?

Comment: Yes. A Python 3 version of our application is deployed alongside the Python 2 version. The Task Queue is still supported via [legacy bundled services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/bundled-services-overview), though they suggest [migrating pull queues to Pub/Sub and push queues to Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services#task_queue). We don't plan on migrating the Task Queue.

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, there is no option to determine or select the default version of a service when traffic is split. The only thing I could observe is when traffic is 100% allocated on one version, that would be considered as a default version, since I am unable to delete it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Before there was an option to just select the default version when you create multiples of it but it was no longer available. Link for the document [here](https://rominirani.com/app-engine-dev-tips-6-understand-application-versions-d5b195b3f36c).

When I migrate all traffic to another version, it would change to `[project-id].[region].r.appspot.com`. I would consider this to be the default version as no other versions are being used and no traffic is being split.

You can check out the definition of `target` wherein:

> Push tasks only; specifies the alternate version or backend on which to run this task, or `DEFAULT_APP_VERSION` to run on the application's default version. You can specify a module or version, a frontend version, or a backend on which to run this task. The string that you specify will be prepended to the domain name of your app. If you specify the `target` argument, do not specify a Host header in the dictionary for the `headers` argument.

Link for the `taskqueue` documentation through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/services/bundled/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/add).

If selecting the default version is badly needed for your project, I would suggest filing for [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). This is not a guarantee that it would be available in the future but it's worth a shot.